# Where can I find documentation for calling the various types in Python's types module?

Tags: python, documentation

While working on some custom serialization, I've been using the `types` module a lot. One thing that really frustrates me is that the documentation says nothing at all on how to actually call the types. An example: `types.CodeType - The type for code objects such as returned by compile().` Yeah sure, what about the **12** arguments it takes??

```
>>> types.CodeType()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
TypeError: code() takes at least 12 arguments (0 given)
```

Now, I can generally wrest the information out from various other places in the Python docs, or on the net. For example, I'm guessing `new.code(argcount, nlocals, stacksize, flags, codestring, constants, names, varnames, filename, name, firstlineno, lnotab)` is the same argument list as expected by `types.CodeType` (although, an argument list hardly counts as a good documentation).

But seriously, does anyone know documentation that actually describes the possible calls in `types`?

**EDIT**: I just noticed one alternative that can be of slight help... `help(types.CodeType)` etc.

Comment: I think this is an obvious bug in the documentation and should really be reported as so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not very useful to actually instantiate the types in the `types` module.  Their purpose is to be used in `isinstance()` calls, and some of them can't be instantiated at all (for example `types.GeneratorType`).

If it's just curiosity, have a look at the documentation available in the interactive interpreter, for example

```
help(types.CodeType)
```

If you really think you *need* to instanciate these types, I would be curious to hear an example use case :)

**Edit**: Here is a complete categorised list of the types in the `types` module for Python 2.5 to 2.7.  If multiple types are put on the same line, they are just aliases for the same type.

- 10 types cannot be instantiated at all:

  ```
  BuiltinFunctionType, BuiltinMethodType
  DictProxyType
  EllipsisType
  FrameType
  GeneratorType
  GetSetDescriptorType
  MemberDescriptorType
  NoneType
  NotImplementedType
  TracebackType
  ```
- 16 types are aliases for built-in names:

  ```
  BooleanType                 bool
  BufferType                  buffer
  ComplexType                 complex
  DictType, DictionaryType    dict
  FileType                    file
  FloatType                   float
  IntType                     int
  ListType                    list
  LongType                    long
  ObjectType                  object
  SliceType                   slice
  TupleType                   tuple
  TypeType                    type
  StringType                  str
  UnicodeType                 unicode
  XRangeType                  xrange
  ```

  To instantiate those, it is preferable to use the built-in name.
- The remaining 6 types have useful docstrings:

  ```
  ClassType
  CodeType
  FunctionType, LambdaType
  InstanceType
  MethodType, UnboundMethodType
  ModuleType
  ```

  `ClassType` and `InstanceType` can be considered obsolete, since they refer to old-style classes.

Comment: Come on, don't pull __this__ kind of answer. The language has these features. They are occasionally used. They should be documented.

Comment: -1 for you. There is code that does use the types module to instantiate code, and there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @jsbueno: That's why I said "generally", and that I'd be curious to hear the exact use case.  I still think that it is "generally" not very useful, and I'm still curious about the use case :) (I know the OP is working on "custom serialisation", but that's not very specific.)

Comment: @porgarmingduod: I gave you a pointer where to find the documentation.

Comment: @sven: If you want to annoy the person asking a question with "you don't need to do this", you can do so in a comment. If your entire answer was 'try help(types.CodeObject)', that's fine. I would have upvoted it regardless of the fact that I actually remembered that method simultaneously, because that is an **answer**.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: I did not mean to annoy you (actually I tried to help).  Often, "don't do it this way" is the right answer to a question because there is a better way of doing things (see also the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)).  If you want to discourage this kind of answer, I have to disagree.

Comment: @sven: There is no rule that says it is always helpful to suggest "don't do it this way". Some questions require such a reply; others not. The fact that I consider "don't instantiate from types.*" a bad reply is not because I globally discourage such questions, and you have no reason to claim I do. It should be obvious that I disagree with your kind of answer in this specific case, because it **IS** useful to instantiate from types.

Comment: One example, in my experience, of a use-case for instantiating the types in `types` is to generate test data for unit tests. For example, when testing code that dynamically introspects modules, you don't want to write a real file to disk and import it; instead you'd pass in an instance of `ModuleType`.

Comment: @poorsod: I'd prefer `imp.new_module()` for that purpose.  In my opinion, the only type you would ever want to directly instantiate from the `types` module is `MethodType`, which is useful in decorators in special situations.

Comment: @SvenMarnach `imp` is gradually being deprecated - is there an equivalent in `importlib`?

Comment: @poorsod: This answer and discussion has been about Python 2.  But agreedm if `imp` gets deprecated or removed at some point in the future, you will probably have to use `types.ModuleType` to instantiate modules.